# where clause in entityDataSource with field from other table entity

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ado.net, where-clause

I've got 3 tables, products, productspercategory and category. 
You can choose a category, after which you get all products from that category listed.

But I cannot seem to get this to work.

I am using entity framework, I have created 2 entitydatasources, one for products and one for productspercategory. I've got the ID from the category in a variable in code.

I have added a where parameter to the productspercategory entitydatasource.

```
 <WhereParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="categoryID" Name="category_id" PropertyName="Value" />
 </WhereParameters>
```

But now I need to add a where parameter to the products entitydatasource to show only the products that are in the productspercategory entitydatasource.
How can I do this?

Database structure:

Category table contains: name, categoryID
Productspercategory table contains: id, categoryID, productID
Product table contains: productID, name

So I want to get all product names in an entitydatasource that belong to the selected categoryID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using an SQLdatasource